# "Operation aborted" error constantly on IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Just upgraded to IE8, and now I'm constantly getting the following error:

```
Windows Internet Explorer
Internet Explorer cannot open the Internet site http://...
Operation aborted
```

Sometimes the page disappears when I click OK, sometimes its still there.

Is this a known issue for IE8?

Comment: Some would view this as a feature to save people from having to use IE ;P

Answer (score 2):

Actually it was a known issue even before, although the IE team [claimed to have fixed it](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2008/04/23/what-happened-to-operation-aborted.aspx). Basically that message meant that the page was trying to manipulate its DOM tree while not fully loaded. Something where the specification says that behaviour is undefined.

They also link to a [Knowledge Base Article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/927917).

But for all I know it's supposed to be fixed<sup>1</sup> in IE 8.

<sup>1</sup> or at least not modal-dialog-in-your-face visible.

Comment: Had this issue extremely rarely with ie7. Happens constantly with ie8.

Comment: Then I'd suggest asking someone on the IE team. I mean, they claimed it was fixed by now.

Comment: Goodness! Surely they had already fix such a _difficult_ issue by IE6! By golly!