# IE 7 error "cannot open the internet site operation aborted"

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer

I am well aware there is already a [similar post](https://superuser.com/questions/4565/operation-aborted-error-constantly-on-ie8) on this subject, but my issue persists.

[image]

I did both suggested workarounds:

1. On the Tools menu, click Internet Options.
2. On the Security tab, select the zone the site loads under.
3. Scroll down to the Scripting section, and set the Active Scripting
   to Disabled - prevents scripts or to Prompt - prompts user to run or
   not to run scripts.
4. Click OK.

and

1. On the Tools menu, click Internet Options.
2. On the Security tab, select the Restricted Sites zone.
3. Click Sites, click Add, and then click OK.

User is running IE7 on Windows XP.

So any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this might not exactly help you, I am going to quote from Microsoft's website:

> The easiest way for you to fix the problem is to upgrade to Internet
>   Explorer 8. This problem no longer occurs in Internet Explorer 8

Source: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927917

Comment: User doesn't really want to because she is fearful that Microsoft would track her internet usage... I tried reasoning with her...  But thank you nonetheless!

Comment: @George Okay, I edited the post with a workaround that should help. EDIT: whoops, never mind, the workaround I have added on (now removed) states that it works for only IE6.

Comment: Track internet usage? Then why use *any* version of IE at all, and not Firefox/Chrome/Opera etc.?

Comment: @Karan That is EXACTLY what I was thinking. Oh well. Some people just can't be convinced, evidently.

Comment: Maybe @George can tell her something to the tune of "with Win8/IE10 being released, IE7 is no longer supported due to security issues", and she needs to update to a newer version of IE or an alternate browser to be safe.

Comment: @Karan I do believe that Microsoft has stopped supporting Windows XP (that includes IE8) entirely a long time ago, but correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Still 1.5 years to go till Extended Support for XP ends in [April 2014](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP#Support_lifecycle). I don't know about IE7's support lifecycle though.